# Why do we have to use two times datetime function for and object in python

Tags: python

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Current date and time:")
print(now.strftime("%T-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

the now object created is why we have to use two times the datetime function

Comment: First datetime is a module, second datetime is an object, now is a method. This is how datetime namespace are organized in python.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? ``datetime`` is something other than ``datetime.datetime``, and neither is a function.

Comment: You can use `from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using "two times the datetime function". In `datetime.datetime.now()`, the function is `now`. The first `datetime` is the package, and the second `datetime` is sub-package. The objects are grouped hierarchically for sake of better organization, for example alongside `datetime.datetime` there is also `datetime.date` (compare `datetime.datetime.now()` with `datetime.date.today()`).

If you do not want to use both levels each time, then instead of:

```
import datetime
```

you could do:

```
from datetime import datetime
```